# count if a word match both columns at once

Tags: r

How to count a specific word present in both the columns at once?

`ab <- data.frame(one = c("abcd","efg","ijk"), two = c("abcd mmmk","abcd qrst","ijk"))`

I need to get the count of abcd only if present in both the columns one and two.

eg: Expected result: count of abcd = 1,

bcos only first row has got both abcd but second row cannot be added since only one row got abcd but the code i tried below gives result as "2"

Please help me to achieve this

**Code:**

`length(grep('abcd',ab$one) & grep('abcd', ab$two))`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `grepl` to check for pattern and use `sum` to count the occurrences.

```
sum(grepl('abcd', ab$one) & grepl('abcd', ab$two))
#[1] 1
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use `grepl` with `sapply` and `rowSums` to count if a *word match all columns*:

```
sum(rowSums(sapply(ab, grepl, pattern="abcd")) == ncol(ab))
#sum(rowSums(!sapply(ab, grepl, pattern="abcd")) == 0) #Alternativ
#[1] 1
```

Answer (score 1):

You can count the number of rows in `which` the pattern `abcd` is repeated across the columns:

```
nrow(ab[which(grepl("(abcd)\\s\\1", apply(ab, 1, paste0, collapse = " "))),])
[1] 1
```

EDIT:

If the pattern is already repeated in a single column, then this would work to match only repetition *across columns*:

Data:

```
ab <- data.frame(one = c("abcd","efg","ijk"), two = c("abcd mmmk","abcd abcd","ijk"))
ab
   one       two
1 abcd abcd mmmk
2  efg abcd abcd # this is the row we do not want to match as the dup is in a single col
3  ijk       ijk
```

The adjustment is that the pattern no longer includes `\\s` and the rows are collapsed without space either:

```
nrow(ab[which(grepl("(abcd)\\1", apply(ab, 1, paste0, collapse = ""))),])
[1] 1
```

Comment: The OP did not provide for that possibility. But it's still a nice question (and I'll think about it...)

Comment: Thought about it and came to some conclusion ... see edit

Comment: What it you change in your new `ab` `ab[1,2]` from `abcd mmmk` to `mmmk abcd`?

Comment: Well, all good questions, but they're asked by you not the OP!

Comment: Yes, that's true. Sorry.

Comment: No prob. (In fact I've been starting to try and find a solution for that ...)

Comment: @GKi Heureka: `ab <- data.frame(one = c("abcd","efg","ijk"), two = c("mmmk abcd","abcd abcd","ijk"))
nrow(ab[which(grepl("(abcd)[^ ].*\\1", apply(ab, 1, paste0, collapse = ""))),])`

Comment: What if ... No I will stop. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

An option with `str_count`

```
library(stringr)
sum(str_count(do.call(paste, ab), 'abcd') == 2)
#[1] 1
```